# Memory Limit Using Regex on massive text file

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file of the following form:

```
('1', '2')
('3', '4')
     .
     .
     .
```

and i'm trying to get it to look like this:

```
1 2
3 4
etc...
```

I've been trying to do this using the re module in python, by chaining together re.sub commands like so:

```
for line in file:
    s = re.sub(r"\(", "", line)
    s1 = re.sub(r",", "", s)
    s2 = re.sub(r"'", "", s1)
    s3 = re.sub(r"\)", "", s2)
    output.write(s3)
output.close()
```

It seems to work great until I get near the end of my output file; then it becomes inconsistent and stops working. I am thinking it is because of the sheer SIZE of the file I am working with; 300MB or approximately 12 million lines.

Can anyone help me confirm that I'm simply running out of memory? Or if it is something else? Suitable alternatives, or ways around this?

Comment: It looks like your file is full of representations of two-tuples of strings representing integers - why?! You could `ast.literal_eval` each line and use `csv` to write it back out.

Comment: It's processing the file line by line, so I don't see how the size of the file should be causing a problem. Are you sure there isn't something else in your code creating an isue?

Comment: You can use a single regex: `output.write(re.sub(r"\(\s*'(\d+)',\s*'(\d+)'\s*\)", r"\1 \2", line))`. But as I say, that's not your problem. You might need to show more of your code to get an answer to that particular issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simplify your code by using a simpler regex that finds all numbers in your input:

```
import re
with open(file_name) as input,open(output_name,'w') as output:
for line in input:
       output.write(' '.join(re.findall('\d+', line))
       output.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't load them as python tuples with [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval). Also instead of opening and closing the files manually you can use `with` statement which close the file at the end of the block :

```
With open(file_name) as input,open(output_name,'w') as output:
    for line in input:
       output.write(','.join(ast.literal_eval(line.strip())))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would used a [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) for better performance.  And the code becomes more readable.

```
# Python 3

from collections import namedtuple
from ast import literal_eval
#...

Row = namedtuple('Row', 'x y')
with open(in_file, 'r') as f, open(out_file, 'w') as output:
    for line in f.readlines():
        output.write("{0.x} {0.y}".
                     format(Row._make(literal_eval(line))))
```

Comment: I got this error(my first line is 35 characters long):
r = Row._make(line)
  File "<string>", line 21, in _make
TypeError: Expected 2 arguments, got 35

Comment: @EliRiekeberg , Okay, updated to fix that -  the answer now converts using `ast.literal_eval` as mentioned by @Kasramvd  which converts from the string line to tuple for input in `namedtuple` and also consolidate `output.write()`

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it without the re module:

```
in_file = open(r'd:\temp\02\input.txt', 'r')
out_file = open(r'd:\temp\02\output.txt', 'w')

for line in in_file:
    out_file.write(line.replace("'", '').replace('(', '').replace(', ', ' ').replace(')', ''))
out_file.close()
```